# Drawable speech/text bubble with same style as Google Messaging app

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable

I'm trying to create a drawable background for messaging, and I would like it to look the same as Google's native Messaging app. Picture example below

[image: What I want]

I'm having trouble with this. Here's the closest I can get:

[image]

Here's the drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:top="8dp">
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="-45"
            android:toDegrees="0"
            android:pivotX="0%"
            android:pivotY="0%" >
            <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
                <stroke android:width="8dp" android:color="#424242" />
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>
    <item android:left="8dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="#424242" />
            <corners android:radius="4dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Any tips on how to achieve the styling from the first picture?

Answer (score 0):

You should create a `nine-patch image` as they are stretchable, repeatable images reduced to their smallest size:

Just choose your image and adjust it as per your requirement. **Nine-patch** creator tool:[Here](http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/nine-patches)